# Flutter - Delay the Firebase Push Notification Prompt

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification

Is there a way to specify when to display the allow push notification prompt when using `firebase` & `flutter`?

It seems that `Firebase.initializeApp();` will display it. This is set within my main file, but I want to only display it during my onboarding flow.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware `Firebase.initializeApp()` wont request permissisons, as this should be handled by the [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) package and can be done with the following code:

```
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );
```

Comment: Right, which is what I thought. And I have that set in a specific area, but for some reason, I'm still getting the prompt right when I open my app.

Comment: Maybe show the contents of your main function